# How to Implement Complex Logic Conditions (AND, OR combinations) from JSON Request Body in Python?

Tags: python, json, logic, operators

I am working on a project where I have to evaluate multiple conditions/checks based on user input from a front-end interface. The user can create combinations of these clauses using logical operators like AND, and OR. For instance, a combination can be (A AND B) OR C, or A AND (B OR C).

An example of the checks:

1. Hire Rate > 90%
2. Total Spent >= 3000$
3. Payment Method Verified = True
4. Is this job related to building a Tech-Product

A possible combination from the user could be: ((Check1 AND Check2) OR Check3) AND Check4

Each Clause set has an associated score, say +2. In my backend, I need to check if the data satisfies these conditions and then assign the corresponding score. I am looking for a way to:
1. Structure the JSON request body from the front end to represent these combinations effectively.
2. Parse and evaluate the received JSON in Python backend. Any guidance or existing libraries that might be helpful for this?

We tried creating a structured JSON for where each clause object had multiple checks for example:
[image]
We need a way to apply the operators between checks.

Comment: my intuition tells me that `jmespath` might help here.